# Restriction in Data Contract Serialization in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am on the mid way of porting a iPhone application to windows phone. As per the client requirement i cant able to use database in the project. In iPhone they are serializing the there object and saves in memory. My doubt is that in the application it saves the favourite, Buddy List, Check in details, Location data , setting etc. I am serializing all these to different  xml files. So my question is is there any restriction present in the case of this xml file. Whether it will introduce any performance issues in the future etc.

Comment: Am I understanding it correctly. You can not use proper database eg sdf, but you want to use XML based database? About data contract, it is not good to use it in that way. it has very few possibities of xml formating and customization, eg no attributes. better will be normal xml serialization.

Comment: My question is,, is there any issue will arise if we add more number of xml file..

Comment: Why can you not use a database on the device? After all, it does not increase the overhead for installation if you follow the principles in t[Isolated storage example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx#BKMK_Fundamental)